# Python - Smooth line (Matplotlib) using BSpline?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to smooth the following red line in my chart (which is a bit bumpy around 150 on the x axis, but am having problems doing it as all the examples i see are using spline which has deprecated (telling me to use BSpline which I can not find any good tutorials for)

The code is:

```
y = np.array([476,310,254,190,184,182,161,154,148,133,127,119,117,103,102,96,95,95,91,84,82,71,65,64,64,64,62,61,49,
 42,38,37,33,30,29,22,22,18,16,16,16,14,12,12,11,10,9,9,9,8,8,6,6,5,4,4,4,4,3,2,1,1])

x = np.array([19,40,35,43,19,18,35,15,31,12,22,19,33,19,43,55,17,6,21,26,20,21,14,53,30,13,42,43,51,43,24,30,36,13,41,41,41,50,56,50,
44,64,58,42,18,30,78,22,11,25,25,50,50,60,100,25,25,0,67,100,100,0])

j = np.array([29,32,34,36,37,37,38,38,39,40,40,41,41,43,43,43,43,43,44,45,45,47,48,48,48,48,
 49,49,52,55,56,57,59,60,61,66,66,71,73,73,73,77,81,81,83,86,89,89,89,92,92,102,
 102,109,118,118,118,118,132,154,201,201])

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.scatter(y,x)
plt.plot(y,j, 'red', linestyle=':', dashes=(1, 5), linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

Picture of graph:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: The code misses how you created the array `j`.

Comment: I just added the numbers from a spreadsheet manually. It will be read in from a CSV file :)

Comment: I was under the impression that those values are created by the spline function you have a problem with?

Comment: Oh I see. I need to spline them before they go into the array?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I understood this to be the problem. If that is not the case, what exactly is the problem you face?

Comment: When I use spline it says it is deprecated and I notice the line isn't smooth. It says to use BSpline but I can't find any tutorials or examples that simplify what I am meant to do... Everything on stackoverflow refers to the spline module

Comment: So you **are** using some spline. In that case we need to see the code you have the problem with, because the code you currently have produces the desired output, right?!

Comment: Ahhhh I see what you mean. Yep that output is working. I'm just at the gym, so when i get home I'll get my work laptop out and will update. Thank you very much